# Does the southern pronunciation of Jenny have a triphthong in it?

Tags: phonetics, dialects, american-english, names, triphthongs

You know when Forrest Gump yells Jenny's name and it sounds like "Jenneay". I'm wondering if there actually is a triphthong at the end there, or of it is a figment of my imagination. I believe the phonetic transcription would be: /dʒɛnæɛɪ/ Is this correct?

Or perhaps the southern pronunciation ends on a much simpler diphthong?

([Reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMuiK1832a0))

Comment: @sumelic I have no idea what that means, but I'll give an example of the sound I thought of: the last vowel in the word he**y**

Comment: @A.Kvåle IPA `/j/` is the first sound in the English word "yes", while IPA `/y/` is the first sound in the German word *über*, or the last sound in the French word *tu*.

Comment: Oh, well of course I meant the IPA meaning of /y/

Comment: Related: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/what-is-an-example-of-a-language-or-dialect-that-contains-triphthongs, https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15372/are-lanas-yups-triphthongs

Comment: If you have a recording of the particular sound you mean, that'll help a lot.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I wasn't talking about that sound, the /j/ sound. I was talking, not about the letter "y" but the international symbol that is /y/. I don't understand the confusion. Why would there even be a /j/ at the end of Jenny, it's not even a vowel. Though, my original transcription was probably a bit inaccurate, as the vowel at the end of "hey" is /ɪ/, which is probably closer to what I was explaining. Still, I feel like your edit wasn't reflective over what I was describing, as there definitely isn't a /j/ at the end of "hey". Sorry if I seemed aggressive but it bugged me a little.

Comment: @A.Kvåle /eɪ/ is fine for the end of "hey", but it can be written /ej/ as well. (You certainly don't mean to use the IPA symbol /y/ anywhere — it's the sound in the French phrase « déjà v**u** ».) The second segment in the "ey" diphthong can be analyzed as a glide, hence /j/. But /ɪ/ is a standard and perfectly fine transcription too. Here's [a good ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/68679/218720) exploring English diphthongs more fully.

Comment: You also need to consider that Gino's accent is. It necessarily exactly what everyone else speaks like in reality. Supposedly Hanks, in training for the role, tried to emulate the speech of one particular Southern boy. Also, Hanks was playing a person with cognitive impairment which may have affected his pronunciation.

Comment: Which enunciation of "Jenny" are you talking about? The first one is too distorted to really tell for sure but it sounds possibly like /ˈdʒæneɪ/, and the rest sound like /ˈdʒɪni/ or /ˈdʒɛni/ to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Phonetically, I would say **no**.

Here's a plot of this final vowel (taken from about 12.75 seconds into the linked video). It's not a great plot, since the recording quality I'm using isn't great, but it'll work for our purposes.

[image: plot exported from praat]

Acoustically, [vowels are determined by values called *formants*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/28968/10559), which appear as horizontal black bars in the spectrum. The red dots also represent the formants, just calculated in a different way.

Well, the positions of these formants are continuous: they can show up at any frequency (within a certain range), not only certain specific values. Which means that the space of vowels is also continuous! When someone pronounces a diphthong, they glide seamlessly from one vowel to another—so a diphthong like `[æi]` starts at `[æ]` *and passes seamlessly through `[e]`* before arriving at `[i]`. In fact, since frequency space is continuous, it passes through an infinite number of different intermediate vowels!

Clearly, calling all vowel sequences "infinity-phthongs" isn't very useful, even though there are indeed an infinite number of intermediate points. So instead, phoneticists generally ignore everything in the middle, and *only pay attention to the critical points*—the start, the end, and anywhere the trajectory changes direction.

For example, a sequence like `[æɛeɪi]` would still be called a "diphthong", since it never changes direction: it moves in a "straight line" from `[æ]` to `[i]`, and we don't really care about the intermediate stuff. If you connect the dots on an IPA vowel chart, you'll get basically a straight line. So we only care about two phthongs.

But a sequence like `[ɑɔoʊuʉy]` would be called a "triphthong", because it changes direction once (try connecting the dots on an IPA vowel chart again and you'll see). So we care about the two endpoints, plus the one direction change in the middle, giving us *three* phthongs.

In this case, there's no real change in direction—the formants are basically straight lines, without any bends or kinks in them. The sound starts somewhere around `[ɛ]` and moves straight to `[i]`. It definitely passes through other vowels on the way, but phonetically, that's just how diphthongs tend to work.

---

P.S. Phonemically, the question is totally different—but I'd also say no. There's no evidence that there are three separate phonemes at the end there; instead, it seems to be an allophone of plain old `/i/`.

P.P.S. This plot was generated with a program called Praat, which is free to download and play around with if you want to do some phonetic experimentation!

P.P.P.S. "Phthong" is not actually a technical term in linguistics. It's just more fun to say than "critical point in the vowel trajectory".